# Batch updating in Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, batch-processing

I am trying to implement batch insert and update as documented in this blog post: https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-hibernate-batch-insert-update

I am having some performance issues with the batch update. I am trying to update around 1 million savings accounts, and each savings account has a `@OneToMany` relationship with savings account transactions. The way I process it is save all the transactions first, then update all the savings accounts. The batch saving/insert processes very quickly, however the batch update takes a long time to finish.

I turned on the SQL logger of hibernate and I saw that it produces two update statements for each savings account: one for savings account and one for the transaction. How do I turn off the update for the transaction?

Any idea on how to optimize the batch updates?

Batch insert of savings account transaction:

```java
        int i = 0;
        for(SavingsAccountTransaction savingsAccountTransaction : savingsAccountTransactionsForSaving) {
            if(i > 0 && i%BATCH_SIZE == 0) {
                entityManager.flush();
                entityManager.clear();
            }

            entityManager.persist(savingsAccountTransaction);
            i++;
        }
```

Batch update of savings account:

```java
        int i = 0;
        for(SavingsAccount savingsAccount : savingsAccountsListForUpdate) {
            if(i > 0 && i%BATCH_SIZE == 0) {
                entityManager.flush();
                entityManager.clear();
            }

            entityManager.merge(savingsAccount);
            i++;
        }
```

Comment: Try using hibernate native query for updation. Please refer to the link -->> https://thoughts-on-java.org/use-native-queries-perform-bulk-updates/

Comment: Hi @NamrataShukla, yes I tried this but it still performs two updates: one for savings account and one for savings account transaciton. Do you know how to prevent the update to transaction?